# No questions are listed when clicking on a tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, questions

When I click on a tag on [the tag page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags), I would like to see the questions that contains that tag, as on StackOverflow. But on the GIS site, no questions are listed.

Why? What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that -- full text indexing wasn't working on this database for some reason. I rebuilt the indexes and it seems better now.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug.
Funny that it works in other stackexchange sites.
Maybe this feature starts working only over certain threshold of questions.

Posted to meta.stackoverflow.com
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58211/gis-se-site-no-questions-are-listed-when-clicking-on-a-tag

Comment: After creating an account there, I was able to vote up the question and added a bounty, maybe if more of us do that we can get it resolved.

Comment: I deleted this post, it's inappropriate for meta.so. I can't reproduce what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the content of those pages is calculated sporadically, like once a day.  Maybe the process that populates that information hasn't been ran yet.

Comment: 2 days have passed, the bug is still there. It's annoying to see that a brand new site has such bugs, even if they disappear later. (when public beta begins?)