# Using tag [esri] for questions about specific Esri packages?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, questions

**Should we allow the `esri` tag** for questions not about the company, but rather about its products?  Currently it is being used to tag questions related to Esri products.

The tags on questions tagged `esri` that I could find at time of writing are listed for convenience (since currently [no questions are listed when clicking on a tag](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/no-questions-are-listed-when-clicking-on-a-tag) ) :

- `esri`  `arcobjects`  `development`
- `esri`  `arcobjects`  `arcgis-server` (was `arcgis.server`)
- `esri` `file-formats` `mxd` `lyr` (relates to formats used by ArcGIS)
- `development`  `esri`  `arcobjects`  `.net`
- `esri`  `spatial-database` `geodatabase`  `arcsde`
- `esri`  `open-source`  `dem` `spatial-analyst` (a question which asks how do I do this without esri spatial analyst)
- `esri`  `arcgis`  `personal-gdb`  `ms-access`  `mdb`
- `esri`  `arcgis`  `.net`  `ags-9.3.1`

Pretty all of these questions are tagged with a specific Esri product or API as well as the generic Esri tag.

Is there, therefore, any merit in retaining a generic Esri tag?

Note that stackoverflow.com currently has 851 questions tagged `microsoft`, 7,667 questions tagged `visual-studio-2008` and 96,362 questions tagged `c#`.

Comment: I think we could have a tag named esri. Someone might be asking for what type of products esri has, and other non technical related stuff?

Comment: I don't see any harm that could result.  Multi tag searches could prove useful, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esri+.net

Comment: @Geroge I agree.  But should we fill it with questions like `How do I do *x* with ArcMap?`

Comment: I think it is fine to have an esri tag available for questions about the company, but for product specific questions I think using it is a "waste of a tag".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it matters.  Colloquially, people won't be phrasing "I'm having trouble doing this task with my ESRI", much the same way nobody (except maybe my Grandpa) would be "having trouble doing that task with his Microsoft".

ESRI is neither a concept nor a single product.  Furthermore, most of their singly-named products are heaped components, but for the sake of understanding, let's stick to commonly accepted tags.

Inappropriate tags are a minor annoyance IMHO.

Comment: If there's some standard out there (e.g. OGC) and I heard ESRI (or Microsoft) has some tool that is compliant with the standard, but don't know the tool, then it would make sense to search for a combination of OGC and ESRI (or Microsoft)

Answer (score 1):

There is a Meta Stack Exchange Q&A that seems to be the equivalent of this one:

[Are company-name tags like [microsoft] and [apple] useful?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190914/are-company-name-tags-like-microsoft-and-apple-useful)

I almost agree with @animuson who says:

> Things like "Microsoft" and "Apple" are users tagging things
>   incorrectly.

However, I would say that an [esri](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri) tag can be used, but only when it is a question about the company itself, rather than one or more of its products, because the latter already have more specific tags like:

- [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop)
- [arcgis-server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-server)
- [arcgis-javascript-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api)
- [esri-geoportal-server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri-geoportal-server)
- [esri-production-mapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri-production-mapping)
- etc

---

The [esri](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri) tag has for quite some time been a synonym of [esri-company](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri-company) with this tag excerpt:

> Use for questions concerning Esri the company rather than its products
>   which have separate tags.

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest that we could handle this in a hierarchical manner, so you'd have tags like:

- `[esri-arccobjects]`
- `[esri-arcgis]`

Maybe even:

- `[esri-shapefile]`
- `[esri-mxd]`

By doing it in a hierachical manner, you can use wildcards in the interested/ignored tags (e.g. `[esri*]`)

Comment: this is a good idea.

esri-ags (arcgis server)
esri-ags-javascript
esri-ags-webadf

esri-sde-admin
esri-sde-oracle
esri-sde-pgsql
esri-sdk-inteface
esri-sdk-class

Comment: yuk. that's what chaining tags together does. I don't want to have to plunk `esri` in front of everything, it's redundant and makes things less flexible. ESRI makes Arcmap, therefore `[arcmap]` is automatically `[esri]`'s child.

Comment: @matt By all means post an alternate suggestion -- I do tend to agree that the esri portion becomes redundant when talking about `[arcmap]` and `[arcgis]` etc (and `[arc*]` still works, although the search based on that tag won't work as the wildcards need more than three letters to work on the search page)

Comment: my point is that I don't think we need an alternate, `[arcmap]` or `[mxd]` on their own are sufficient most of the time. On those occasions when more generality is wanted it can be chained, `[esri] [arcmap]`, though I admit to not being able to imagine a case where this would be useful.